# What does don't cares and null do in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

What does setting a value to don't cares actually mean and do in VHDL? Also what's the difference between setting the values to don't care vs setting it to null?
Here's a snippet from the lab I'm doing:

```
with selector select
    mux_data_selected <=    Channel_1_registered_data when '0';
                            Channel_2_registered_data when '1';
                            (others => '-') when others;
```

Comment: If you set a signal to "don't care", a synthesizer or a simulator is free to use any value. If you set it to "0", it must assign zero.

Comment: The only thing you can set to null is an access type aka pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the elements of `mux_data_selected` is probably `std_ulogic` or one of the like. To answer your last question, there is no `null` value in these types, so you cannot assign `(others => null)`.

`null` is a void instruction that does nothing and that is sometimes used to indicate that there is nothing to be done in a branch of the control flow and that it is intentional.

It is also a pointer value (access types). Finally we sometimes talk about null arrays but it means that the array has an empty range, like `1 to 0`, for instance. If your vector has a non-null range you cannot assign it a null array value, this would cause an error.

The `-` don't care value is one of the 9 values of the `std_ulogic` enumerated type. As its name says it is for cases where you do not care about the value. Either because you know this situation will never happen in real life or because when the situation happens you do not use the signal.

A smart enough logic synthesizer can use this indication to implement any actual `'0'` or `'1'` value that improves one metric (speed, area, power...) While if you code, e.g., `'0'` the synthesizer is forced to obey, which could lead to a speed, area or power waste.

As noted by @user16145658 the `'-'` value is also treated as a match anything wildcard by VHDL2008 `STD_MATCH` functions and predefined matching relational operators (`?=`, `?/=`, `?<`, `?<=`, `?>`, and `?>=`). So you can use it also for soft comparisons.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 16.8 Standard synthesis packages, 16.8.2.2 The STD_LOGIC_1164 values  "The  value  '–'  is  also  called  the  *don’t  care  value*.  This  standard  treats  it  in  the  same  way  as  the  other metalogical values except when it is furnished as an actual parameter to the STD_MATCH functions in the IEEE.NUMERIC_STD  package or as  an  operand  to  a predefined matching  relational operator (see  9.2.3). The STD_MATCH functions and the predefined matching relational operators use '–' to implement a “match all” or “wild card” matching". Also see 16.8.2.4.4 - 16.8.2.4.10.

Comment: @user16145658 Good point, this is another use of don't cares. I edit my answer to add it.

Comment: Thank your for the answers

Comment: You're welcome. If it answers your question wait a bit for other (and possibly better) answers and... [you know what to do next](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Taking user16145658 thoughts into application, maybe we want to use 'X' as the don't care value for assignments (tools allow this) rather than '-' used in OP example and use the value '-' for a don't care in a matching relational, case? or std_match.   It would be a bummer to assign a '-' to a output and later have the simulation interpret it in a ?= as a don't care.

Comment: @JimLewis Very good point. Having the `-` used for similar, but different, purposes in synthesis and simulation is probably not ideal. But I am a bit uncomfortable with the idea of using `X` as a synthesis don't care. It would break my strategy for visual inspection of waveforms which basically consists in `X=bug`. What about a new ternary operator `val1 ??= val2 : lit_mask` where `'1'`values of `lit_mask` would force literal comparison? Or something similar?

Comment: I find the need for `'-'` as a target of an assignment to be rare.   It only violates your `X=bug` rule when the case statement maps a hardware value of the target to a `'-'`.    In the case above, by your rules, the appropriate value is `'X'` as it was a non-hardware value on the input that generated the value.    Consider a 3 input mux coded as a case statement that does not use the select value "11",  do you code `when "11" => Y <= '-'` or do you code `when "11" => Y <= 'X'`   Generally I am too lazy to separately code the `"11"` condition, so I use `'X'`

Comment: I code `when "11" => Y <= '-'` and, if the selector is not a `bit_vector`, I add `when others => Y <= 'X'`. But I admit that this is probably not very important.